# Where can I find some in-depth DirectX 11 tutorials?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, directcompute

So far the only tutorials I've been able to find are on [directx11tutorials.com](http://www.directx11tutorials.com/), which are essentially inferred from the existing samples. Does anyone know where to find other tutorials, or better yet open source projects using DirectX 11? (Extra points for project code using DirectX 11 :) )

Comment: How about making this community wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are still no *DX11* tutorials / books. If you want to study *DirectX* in-depth, you could grab some *DX10* book and also examine *DX11 SDK* and *MSDN*.

There is nothing **really new** in DirectX 11 *(in application architecture / code building principles)*, so you could examine new API features and *(if you're actually proficient with DirectX)*, getting used to them should not be very hard.

In this case you simply won't need any tutorials.

*If you need some actual code samples, [this](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/query/#q=D3D11) (and other `DX11` searches) could probably help you.*

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head but I think there are a bunch of new stages in the rendering pipeline (most excitedly the new tessalator), but that might have been my memory of DirectX 10. 

Thanks for suggesting Google code, I didn't even know that existed!

Comment: Did you mean to write, "getting used to them should *not* be very hard?"

Answer (score 8):

You can check those links that are valuable resources for learning DX11:

- [http://www.yakiimo3d.com/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120814123940/http://www.yakiimo3d.com/)
- http://gpuexperiments.blogspot.com/
- http://users.skynet.be/fquake/
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140408062150/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/directx/archive/2010/06/15/introducing-the-directcompute-lecture-series.aspx)
- http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/gclassy/DirectCompute-Expert-Roundtable-Discussion/
- http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/P09-16
- http://www.rorydriscoll.com/

Answer (score 7):

You might also want to check out

http://www.braynzarsoft.net

Comment: I can only recommend these tutorials. Even though the author sometimes forgets to mark new passages in a highlight color as he did from the start, it goes on pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you need a really in-depth understanding of concepts, Frank Luna's book [Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936420228) is by far the best book on DirectX 11.

Also there is a good beginner level easy to follow video tutorial series on YouTube [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpLMSbxKEIU)

Answer (score 1):

One book that I think is very useful for DirectX11 even if you not doing game programming is [Beginning DirectX 11 Game Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458958) book . Excellent source of information.